# Higher-order/chaining functions in rust using pyo3

Tags: rust, pyo3

I'm having issues with attempting to call functions from within other functions in pyo3 with rust.

When I try, and change the output type to a pyresult to get the functions to chain together, I just end up with a whole host of other errors and I was wondering if anyone knew what I need to do to make these functions work together in pyo3.

```rust
use ndarray;
use numpy::{IntoPyArray, PyArray1, PyArray2, PyArrayDyn, PyReadonlyArrayDyn, PyReadonlyArray1};
use pyo3::prelude::*;

/// Formats the sum of two numbers as string.

#[pyfunction]
fn generate_data() -> (Vec<f64>, Vec<f64>) {
    let x_values = vec![0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.10, 0.20, 0.50, 1.00, 2.00, 5.00];
    let y_values = vec![129867.0, 284533.0, 655220.0, 1469586.0, 3359871.0, 5820969.0, 13009337.0, 22875222.0, 43101398.0];

    let x_values_f64: Vec<f64> = x_values.into_iter().map(|x| x as f64).collect();
    let y_values_f64: Vec<f64> = y_values.into_iter().map(|y| y as f64).collect();

    (x_values_f64, y_values_f64)
}

#[pyfunction]
fn calculate_mean(
   
    values: PyReadonlyArrayDyn<f64>) -> f64 {
    let values = values.as_array();
    let n = values.len() as f64;    
    let values = values.iter().sum::<f64>() / n;
    values
}

#[pyfunction]
fn calculate_slope(x_vals: PyReadonlyArrayDyn<f64>, y_vals: PyReadonlyArrayDyn<f64>) -> f64 {

 

    let x_vals =  x_vals.as_array();
    let y_vals = y_vals.as_array();

    let x_vals_n = x_vals.len() as f64;
    // let x_vals_mean = x_vals.iter().sum::<f64>() / x_vals_n;        

    let y_vals_n = y_vals.len() as f64;
    // let y_vals_mean = y_vals.iter().sum::<f64>() / y_vals_n; 

   

    let x_vals_mean = calculate_mean(x_vals);
    let y_vals_mean = calculate_mean(y_vals);

    let numerator = x_vals
        .iter()
        .zip(y_vals.iter())
        .map(|(&xi, &yi)| (xi - x_vals_mean) * (yi - y_vals_mean))
        .sum::<f64>();

    let denominator = x_vals
        .iter()
        .map(|&xi| (xi - x_vals_mean).powi(2))
        .sum::<f64>();

    numerator / denominator
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
--> src/lib.rs:45:38
|
45 | let y_vals_mean = calculate_mean(y_vals);
| -------------- ^^^^^^ expected PyReadonlyArray<'_, f64, Dim<IxDynImpl>>, found ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&f64>, Dim<IxDynImpl>>
| |
| arguments to this function are incorrect
|
= note: expected struct PyReadonlyArray<'_, f64, Dim<IxDynImpl>>
found struct ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&f64>, Dim<IxDynImpl>>
```

I've tried changing types back and forth to a number of different options but end up with a list of different errors.

Comment: Please don't post external links to your code, inline all the code necessary to reproduce your problem (and error messages too). (I think you want to define a `fn calculate_mean_base(values: ndarray::ArrayBase<...>)` and then call that from `#[pyfunction] fn calculate_mean`. Not that I know anything about pyo3 or ndarray.)